# Using an angular2 app as a plugin for HawtIO

Tags: angularjs, angular, hawtio

Is it possible to use an entire Angular2 app as a plugin within HawtIO? Our reasoning for doing this is so that as we develop our OSGi applications, each having their own UI, we can use HawtIO as the overall container and can detect and display each UI webapp within.

From what I have investigated so far, it looks like the only possibility is either adding simple plugins which add static links to our individual web apps, or re-write the Angular2 app as a AngularJS one instead?

Answer (score 0):

The hawtio-core component from hawtio 2.x supports bootstrapping a hybrid angular 1/2 app which is pretty much what you're looking for:

https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio-core

It's been awhile but I played around with it in this branch from the fabric8-console project, it may need some adjusting to be inline with new angular2 developments:

https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-console/tree/angular2/plugins/angular2/ts